# Stopped being able to run exes and msis on Windows 11 via mouse double-click

Tags: windows-registry, windows-installer

I must have done something that messed up with Windows settings leaving me unable to run exes nor msis by double clicking them.

They will run, however, if running them via CLI, either by manually running the '.exe' or, for msi, running `msiexec.exe`.

I tried most of what is suggested [here](https://thegeekpage.com/fix-exe-files-not-opening-in-windows-10/) (skipped the "sound & user account" stuff which sound too hardcore) (most of the suggested stuff is what I already have). No avail.

1. How can I figure out what is happening ?
2. How do I fix this ?!

Don't see errors in `Event Viewer`.
Double clicking does nothing.
No process is opened/shown in `Task Manager`.

---

**Update (1)**:
Tried enabling Windows Installer Logging as instructed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/application-management/enable-windows-installer-logging).
I can't see a new log file created when I try to run a msi.

---

**Update (2)**
Followed `harrymc` suggestions. Ran:

1. `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`
   [image]
2. `sfc /scannow`
   [image]

Nothing changed.

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: @harrymc: article mentions Windows 10. Is it relevant for Win 11 ?

Comment: Running the commands does not require reading the supplied links. However, with small changes to account for Windows 11 (ISO etc.), the methods are the same.

Comment: @harrymc: I did not realize your links were commands. Trying them out.

Answer (score -1):

Ideas that you could try:

- Try restarting.
- Can you open files with other extensions (e.g. a `.txt` file)?
- Can you run .exes from alternative file managers (e.g. Total Commander)? Try downloading another file manager, opening it using the command line (which you said still works) and then try to run another `.exe` file from the new file manager.
- Is the file association for `.exe` and `.msi` correct? Check the following two Registry entries:

  1. `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.exe\PersistentHandler`, property `(Default)`; the value is `{098f2470-bae0-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}` on my computer
  2. `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msi.Package\shell\Open\command`, property `(Default)`, the value is `"%SystemRoot%\System32\msiexec.exe" /i "%1" %*` on my computer

  If one of them has a different value, back up the current value, overwrite it with the values above and try if that fixes the issue (if it doesn't change the value back so that it doesn't cause more problems).

Comment: 1. Restarted a couple of times, obviously. 2. No exe opens, regardless of file manager in use (for instance, downloading total commander and double clicking the download exe from chrome - does nothing).
3. My values for those 2 keys and yours are swapped. Which Windows are you using ? What are the types you see in those 2 keys in the registry ? `command` key is of type  `REG_EXPAND_SZ` while `PersisentHandler` is `REG_SZ`

Comment: Please note that SE communities are not discussion boards. Answers are strictly for providing valid answers to the questions asked. Clarifying questions, suggestions etc. belong to Comments. You're allowed to comment when your reputation passes 50, and you gain reputation by providing good answers. Similarly bad answers remove reputation. Please check the Help / Answering -section to get a handle on how answering works.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1171362)